# How can The Flash breathe when running?

Tags: dc, the-flash

I'm not aware of everything that is in The Flash lore (comics, animated series, etc.) but I did watch some of it to notice that, I never saw an explanation on how he can breathe when running?

By that, I mean, the faster you run, the more you would normally breathe.

I understand it's either probably just omitted for the plot/because it's fiction, or maybe it's explained somewhere I overlooked.

As for which instance of "The Flash" I'm referencing... well, I wouldn't know myself given I don't know enough of the lore (as already stated) but I guess it can be taken as a "general" question, rather than specific.

Comment: There's already a similar question in the archives, with a couple of answers: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/23315/how-does-the-flash-breathe-while-utilizing-his-super-speed#:~:text=It%27s%20simple.,become%20forms%20of%20living%20energy.

Comment: right, didn't found it when i searched :D @LogicDictates

Comment: No worries. I recommend Googling a question first to see if any of the relevant results link back to this site. - @Nordine Lotfi

Comment: I did (as already mentioned) though i didn't try to do so on the actual stackexchange site!

Comment: Okay, you didn't say where you'd searched. It was one of the top results on Google for me. - @Nordine Lotfi

Comment: Used duckduckgo if i recall. Didn't thought of using Google at the time :) @LogicDictates